# incrementing/decrementing n-bit binary by recursion (algorithm)

Tags: algorithm, recursion, permutation

I have a homework problem in which We're supposed to come up with a recursive algorithm for finding seven permutations of an n-bit binary number, starting with 0 (e.g. if n=4 then the starting number is 0000). The rule is to come up with the smallest possible changes in the number, changing only 1 bit at a time with the smallest decimal result possible.

According to the rules, the first permutation would be 0001 (1 in decimals),the second would be 0011 (3 in decimals), the third 0010, and so on.
The permutations I was given in the problem were these:
1. 0000 = 0
 
2. 0001 = 1
3. 0011 = 3
4. 0010 = 2
5. 0110 = 6
6. 0100 = 4
7. 0101 = 5

I know and understand how recursion works but I'm only able to do the simple ones (number sequences, factorials, permutations and so on), I have no idea whatsoever how to come up with the recursive algorithm, can someone please help?

Comment: Have you tried anything? show us your approach.

Comment: @jbsu32 i'm so sorry i don't really have anything in mind :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "smallest decimal result possible" if you're only wanting the 7 smallest binary strings as you would always just have `0` - `110` but if for some reason you don't want to use `C++` `mapping`:

```java
public class f {
    static int count = 0;
    static int n = 7;// n smallest binary strings

    /**
     * 
     * @param str initialize with ""
     * @param len number of bits
     */
    static void g(String str,int len){
        if(count<n) {
            if (len == 0) {
                count++;
                System.out.println(str);
            } else {
                g(str + "0", len - 1);
                g(str + "1", len - 1);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        g("",4);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way ->

```
void rec(string s)
{
    mapped[s]=true;                 /// Mapping the string, which will stop repetition
    cout<<s<<endl;                  /// Printing s
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){         /// looping through s
        if(!mapped[toggle(s,i)]){   /// checking if toggled string is mapped
            rec(toggle(s,i));       /// Calling the toggled string
        }
    }
}
```

Here, `s=0000` & `toggle` switches the `i-th` bit of the string `s`. Here is the `toggle` function for you ->

```
string toggle(string s, int pos){
    if(s[pos]=='1')s[pos]='0';
    else s[pos]='1';
    return s;
}
```

The code block outputs this ->

```
0000
1000
0000
0100
1100
1110
0110
0010
1010
1011
0011
0111
1111
1101
0101
0001
1001
```

You can stop printing at any where you wish!!

Comment: i'm still a bit confused, what exactly does "mapped" do?

Comment: A string is `mapped` if its printed earlier.

Comment: how can we know if it's been printed earlier or not? i'm sorry, i'm very clueless about this.

Comment: Do you have idea about `C++` and `mapping`??? Here you go -> http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/map/